# Find the data elements in a data frame that pass the rule for a node in a tree model?

Tags: r, rpart

So I have used the rpart package to create a tree model and I found an interesting rule and wondered if there was an easy way to see which observations in that data frame pass that rule.

It seems very tedious to use path.rpart to find the path it took down the tree, and manually enter those filters into the data frame to look for them. Is there a method where I can pass a tree and/or a node, and a data frame and return all the elements in that frame that ended at that node?